# Duration data type in TimeIntervalDto object

Tags: clockify

I am creating a database to store time entries that have been created in Clockify, I need to declare a data type for the duration field.  A string is returned in the TimeIntervalDto and an example provided in the API documentation is "PT1M4S" or "PT1H30M15S".  This is obviously a meaningful string if you know how to decode it.

The example given in the API documentation is:

"timeInterval": {
      "duration": "PT1M4S", (Example: PT1H30M15S - 1 hour 30 minutes 15 seconds)
      "end": "2018-06-12T14:01:41Z",
      "start": "2018-06-12T14:00:37Z"
    },

My questions are:

1. How to I translate duration to something meaningful; and
2. What is the maximum size I would need to cater for, assuming that I'm using varchar, or nvarchar as the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with the ISO 8601:2004(en) duration ISO format.

You have a pattern like the follow: "PnnYnnMnnDTnnHnnMnnS"

In detail:

- The letter P represent a Period Format
- Each letter represent a different value, for example if you want to indicate a period of two year, use 02Y.
- For hours use the letter T.

So for your question:

If you can use C# languange before saving to database you can decode de pattern using something like this:

```
 String pattern = "PT1H30M15S";
 TimeSpan ts = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(pattern); //Use System.Xml because it works with ISO 8601:2004
```

You can look for further information on in the ISO webpage. https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8601:ed-3:v1:en

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres Database, you can create a new column based on end and start columns. So you don't need to create a new column just for the duration as it is already implicit with the other two columns.

If you want to get the durations you could do this query:

```
SELECT (t.end - t.start) as "duration", t.start, t.end from t
```

This will return you a new column "duration" in *interval* type.

---

If you really want to create a new column you could do a SQL trigger to fill a column "duration" of type *interval* using "start" and "end" columns every time a new entry is added to the table.